# rsyslog mmextenal logstash json output with escaped quotations and additional quotations

Tags: json, escaping, logstash, rsyslog

I'm having an issue with getting rsyslog to generate the correct format for logstash.  I'm receiving remote rsyslog messages (using RELP) and I'm then processing those messages using some bespoke code loaded via mmexternal.  The output of the mmexternal bespoke code is in the form of a string representing a json object detailing the desired fields from the original message.  The object was created using a json libray and then converted to a string (i.e. `std::string output Json::writeString(builder, jsonObject);`)   This appears to work correctly if I output the data to a log file to an omfile type (my_rsyslog.conf).  This output is intended to form an 'inner' portion of the json message going to logstash, i.e. the outer portion is to be fed by rsyslog itself with timestamp, severity, procid, etc. to be handled outside of the mmexternal bespoke code.  The output looks correct and the quotes for json keys and values (when required) are not escaped.

However, when I attempt to place the output into a json template in rsyslog I get the inner json malformed with escape characters for the quotation marks.  This become a problem for logstash since only part of the message it receives is useful, i.e. only the timestamp, severity , procid, etc.  The json block inner is not useable by logstash.

I'm using AlmaLinux9, Rsyslog 8.2102.0-113.el9_2, Logstash 8.8.2-1.

I have tried this template (found on https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-centralize-logs-with-rsyslog-logstash-and-elasticsearch-on-ubuntu-14-04):

```
template(name="json-template"
  type="list") {
    constant(value="{")
      constant(value="\"@timestamp\":\"")     property(name="timereported" dateFormat="rfc3339")
      constant(value="\",\"sysloghost\":\"")  property(name="hostname")
      constant(value="\",\"severity\":\"")    property(name="syslogseverity-text")
      constant(value="\",\"procid\":\"")      property(name="procid")
      constant(value="\",\"message\":\"")     property(name="msg" format="json")
    constant(value="\"}\n")
}
```

In the logstash output (I'm running in foreground mode) all fields look correct except for message field, it looks like this:

```
"@timestamp" => 2023-08-29T<blah blah>,
<another correctly formatted field>,
"message" => "{ \"blocks*\": [\"blockID\"...< more stuff>...] }", # unwanted quotes enclosing string and escaped quotes within.
```

For the formatting of the message field I've played with json, jsonf, jsonr and jsonfr.  None appear to make a difference.

I have also removed the quotations enclosing the message field that like this:

```
      constant(value="\",\"message\":")     property(name="msg" format="json")
    constant(value="}\n")
```

but this just mangles the output more.

I've also looked at using the 'easier' to use newer template format (found here: https://rainer.gerhards.net/2018/02/simplifying-rsyslog-json-generation.html) but I get the same results:

```
template(name="json-template" type="list" option.jsonf="on") {
    property(outname="@timestamp"
             name="timereported" 
             dateFormat="rfc3339" format="jsonf")
    property(outname="message"
             name="msg" format="jsonf")
}
```

Interestingly if I change jsonf to json I get many more escape characters to each quotation mark, i.e. `\\\\\\\"`

Any help will be much appreciated.

Sean.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, the message field is a pre-fromatted json object, therefore no need to apply formatting, also need to remove the additional quotes around the field, so the template looks like this:

```
template(name="json-template"
  type="list") {
    constant(value="{")
      constant(value="\"@timestamp\":\"")     property(name="timereported" dateFormat="rfc3339")
      constant(value="\",\"sysloghost\":\"")  property(name="hostname")
      constant(value="\",\"severity\":\"")    property(name="syslogseverity-text")
      constant(value="\",\"procid\":\"")      property(name="procid")
      constant(value="\",\"message\":")     property(name="msg") #<<< changes here
    constant(value="}\n") #<<< changes here
}
```